# Lightweight on top of heavyweight

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a JFrame that has a JLayeredPane.  The JLayeredPane contains a heavyweight component (Ardor3d AWT canvas).  I am trying to display a JPanel on top of the heavyweight component.  This works perfectly until I set the size of the frame to the size of my monitor.  The heavyweight seems to draw over the Jpanel that I want on top.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use AWT components exclusively

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/

Comment: Article from wayback machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20101124061105/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is why you should not mix heavyweight and lightweight components. Extend JComponent and override paintComponent() instead of using a canvas.

You mention Ardor3d, I assume that is some sort of 3rd party component.  If there is not a Swing version I would suggest finding something else to meet your need.

Comment: There has been an update which partially solved the issue. See other answer.

Comment: I had not see that yet.  Interesting.